# New to REST - adding a web service class instance to a hashSet

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I've been going through [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/) and they added a web service class instance to a hashSet, like this:

```
public class MessageApplication extends Application {
private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

public MessageApplication() {
    singletons.add(new MessageRestService());
}

@Override
public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    return singletons;
}
```

}

I do not understand what the purpose of it is... I thought you could just access the web service with a URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a class, this class is able to handle web requests. But this class has to be hosted somewhere. This means, this class has to be activated by a URL route. In this case you're using JBOSS.

In the first option of the tutorial, MKyong shows you how to configure RESTEasy Bootstrap (a bootstrap to load references) to map the URL with your class. This is done in web.xml and configures some kind of scanner that will map a certain URL with your class.

The second option is not using RESTEasy Bootstrap and you have to add your class to a collection of long living objects in your application manually. This is done defining the Application (MessageAplication) and defining it in the web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the webservice via a URL, but the server needs to know what to do with calls to a certain URL.

Yours is one way (the bootstrap version) of telling the application server where to look for JAX-RS resources: http://www.mastertheboss.com/resteasy/resteasy-tutorial (Step #4)

There is a (newer) alternative, depending on which server and RESTeasy-version you use, which relies on autoscanning for certain annotations. For RESTeasy on JBoss, it's described at the bottom of the tutorial-page I linked.